# Facing difficulty in running flask app using conda environment

Tags: python, flask, conda

Below is the app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from modules import split_audio, remove_audio, frames, vocals
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/ajax', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filename = request.form['filename']
        fname = request.form['fname']
        if request.form['token'] == 'gvs':
            remove_audio(filename,fname)
            return jsonify({'msg':'pvs'})
        if request.form['token'] == 'gas':
            split_audio(filename,fname)
            return jsonify({'msg':'pas'})
        if request.form['token'] == 'gv':
            vocals(filename,fname)
            return jsonify({'msg':'gv'})
        if request.form['token'] == 'gf':
            no_of_frames = frames(filename,fname)
            return jsonify({'msg':'di', 'no_of_frames': no_of_frames})

@app.route('/file_uploaded', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def file_uploaded():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.files['file']:
            f = request.files['file']
            filename = (secure_filename(f.filename))
            res = filename.find('.mp4')
            fname=''
            for i in range(0, res):
                fname += filename[i]
            path = './static/video/'+fname
            if not os.path.exists(path):
                os.makedirs(path)
            f.save(os.path.join(path, filename))
            return render_template('play.html', filename=filename, fname=fname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=30006, debug=True)
```

Below is the terminal response on running the app.

```
(conda_venv) C:\Users\Muhammad Aleem\Desktop\vas\APP>flask run
failed to create process.

(conda_venv) C:\Users\Muhammad Aleem\Desktop\vas\APP>python -m flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
22050
```

I am facing hard time to understand why this [0.0.0 ... 0.0.0.] 22050 is coming up. I tried to changed the port but still same issue came up. Flask app runs fine, when I create environment using pip. But when create environment using conda it shows these codes which I am unable to understand.
I tried to search on google but couldn't find a solution.
If anyone knows the solution please help me.
Thank you.